# Indy10 Readln and ByteEncoding

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-xe4

I would like to use `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn` in Indy10 on my IdTcpServer but I don't know how to use the ByteEncoding Parameter. Does the client have to send a WideString or AnsiString?

Comment: The last paragraph of [`this post`](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/200903/0903221365.html) will answer your question.

Comment: @TLama It doesn't quite work. `TIdTextencoding.UTF8` could be not found. Any other ideas?

Comment: The `TIdTextEncoding` type is defined in the `IdGlobal.pas` unit.

Comment: @TLama Yep. That's it. Thank you very much :) Should I delete the question?

Comment: It's upon you :-) You can still wait for some extensive answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in control of both the client and server code, then you decide what specific encoding the client sends the text as (UTF-8 is a good choice), and then code the server accordingly.  Indy defaults to ASCII, but you can change that.  However, if you are not in control of the client code, then you need to find out what encoding the client is actually using so that you can then code the server accordingly.  Don't just make blind assumptions.  Find out what is actually being used.